# useState is not updating state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting information from 2 apis, one which is the Unsplash api which returns an random image and a 2nd api which returns a bible verse from ourmanna.com via the cors-anywhere proxy. The unsplash api works fine and always returns an image. The bible api returns the correct data but the useState does not update the state and verse stays as an empty string. I can't see why this is the case.

Below is the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from "react";
import styles from "./BibleQuote.module.css";
import axios from "axios";
import Poster from "../Poster/Poster";
const UNSPLASH_API = process.env.REACT_APP_UNSPLASH_API;
const UNSPLASH_API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_UNSPLASH_API_KEY;

function BibleQuote() {
  const [photo, setImage] = useState({ poster: "" });
  const [verse, setVerse] = useState({ verse: "" });

  useEffect(() => {
async function fetchData() {
  await axios(UNSPLASH_API, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Client-ID ${UNSPLASH_API_KEY}`,
    },
  }).then((res) => {
    setImage(res.data.urls.regular);
    console.log("image", res.data.urls.regular);
  });
  await axios(
    `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.ourmanna.com/verses/api/get?format=text&order=random`).then((res) => {
         setVerse(res.data);
         console.log("APIquote", res.data);
         console.log("State: Quote", verse);
           });
         }
    fetchData();
   }, []);

 return (
   <Fragment>
     <Poster photo={photo} quote={verse} />
   </Fragment>
  );
 }

export default BibleQuote;
```

this is the result in the chrome developer tools:

[image: chrome developer output]

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure it is updated but you can not see it from console.log right after the state is changed. Try to use another one useEffect working only when state is changed.

```
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(false)
  useEffect(()=> {
    setData(true)
    console.log(data) //shows false despite of setData on the previous line
  }, [])
  useEffect(()=> {
    console.log(data) //shows true - updated state
  }, [data])
  return <h2>Hello world</h2>
}
```

That's because setState works async so the next line always contain the previous value of the state.